# Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Cancelled, Detail="Bad gRPC response. Expected HTTP status code 200. Got status code: 400")

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, microservices

I am trying to consume a GRPC api from my Basket API. Every thing is properly connected, but somehow I get this error below:

```
   Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Cancelled, Detail="Bad gRPC response. 
   Expected HTTP status code 200. Got status code: 400")
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.GetResponseAsync()
   at Basket.API.GrpcServices.DiscountGrpcService.GetDiscount(String productName) in 
   /xxxx/Basket.API/GrpcServices/DiscountGrpcService.cs:line 18
   at Basket.API.Controllers.BasketController.UpdateBasket(ShoppingCart basket) in 
   /xxxx/Basket.API/Controllers/BasketController.cs:line 44
   at lambda_method5(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor
   .AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper,  
   ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker. 
   <InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, 
   ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker. 
   <InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task 
    lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure
   .ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& 
   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker. 
   <InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task 
   lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker. 
   <InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, 
   State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker. 
   <InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable 
   scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker. 
   <InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable 
   scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware. 
   <Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger 
   logger)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext 
   context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext 
   httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext 
   httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware. 
   <Invoke>g__AwaitMatcher|8_0(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext 
   httpContext, Task`1 matcherTask)
   at 
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics
  .DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I have registered all the required services at both client and server and made sure all the required functions exists in them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the *incompatible* version of **Grpc.AspNetCore** package at my client api(BASKET.API). The target framework of my API is **net6.0**. When I added a grpc to the connected services, it automatically added versioon 2.23.2. Instead I downgraded it to 2.23.0 and it worked for my.